# External SMTP giving SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Ok: queued as CA053776D18 Mail Not Sent

Tags: php, email, smtp, external, phpmailer

I have an html form which uses php to send the form data in an email to an external mail server. My code is this(variables changed to protect the innoicent):

```
<?php

//$ckNotify = $_POST['ckNotify'];
$ckNotify = isset($_POST['ckNotify']) && $_POST['ckNotify'] ? "Please sign me up for Email Notifications" : "NO";

$ckUnsubscribe = isset($_POST['ckUnsubscribe']) && $_POST['ckUnsubscribe'] ? "Plese unsubscribe me from Email Notifications" : "Does Not Apply to this instance";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (!empty($_POST)) //Validate first
{
    if (empty($name) || empty($visitor_email)) {
        echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
        exit;
    }
}

if (IsInjected($visitor_email)) {
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
// 3 = verbose messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "74.84.86.134";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 25;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('miket@extsmtp.net', 'Mike Tolliver');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('miket@extsmtp.net', 'Mike Tolliver');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('miket@extsmtp.net', 'Mike Tolliver');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'New Form Submission';
//Get message contents from form and place in body of email as basic plain-test
$body = "Email Notifications: $ckNotify
UnSubscribe User: $ckUnsubscribe
Name: $name
Email: $visitor_email
Message: $message";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
//$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

//done - redirect to thank-you page if no errors
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    header('Location: ThankYou.html');
//echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Mail Not Sent";
}

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array(
        '(\n+)',
        '(\r+)',
        '(\t+)',
        '(%0A+)',
        '(%0D+)',
        '(%08+)',
        '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if (preg_match($inject, $str)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this output after submitting the form and going to the php page:

```
    2015-02-03 23:18:21 Connection: opening to 74.84.86.134:25, t=10, opt=array ( ) 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 Connection: opened 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 barracuda.platinum-corp.com ESMTP (b35451cd44f584ec6f962de7068c7240) 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.extsmtp.net 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-barracuda.platinum-corp.com Hello www.extsmtp.net [173.0.129.93], pleased to meet you 250-SIZE 100000000 250-STARTTLS 250-PIPELINING 250-8BITMIME 250 HELP 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Sender OK 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Recipient OK 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Start mail input; end with . 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 3 Feb 2015 17:18:21 -0600 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Return-Path: miket@extsmtp.net 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Mike Tolliver 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Mike Tolliver 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-to: Mike Tolliver 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: New Form Submission 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <718f56184800b47dd0a9327e8003f4f1@www.extsmtp.net> 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_718f56184800b47dd0a9327e8003f4f1" 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_718f56184800b47dd0a9327e8003f4f1 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer! 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_718f56184800b47dd0a9327e8003f4f1 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Email Notifications: Please sign me up for Email Notifications 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: UnSubscribe User: Does Not Apply to this instance 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Name: Joyce Small 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Email: jsmall@somewhere.net 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message: Test message using external smtp settings 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: 2015-02-03 23:18:21   CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_718f56184800b47dd0a9327e8003f4f1-- 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: . 
2015-02-03 23:18:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Ok: queued as CA053776D18 Mail Not Sent
```

It looks like everything is fine to me (but then again, I'm a newbie to php) with the exception of the "Mail not Sent" at the end. Does anyone know why the mail isn't being sent? Based on my very limited knowledge, it seems that the external smtp server isn't relaying - but what do I know. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to look in your mail server log and local config. It looks like it's set to blackhole all messages (or at least ones from you), which is fairly common for a testing config.

Comment: Ah, there is one thing - you're using a very old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest from github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Also, why have you written that `IsInjected` function - PHPMailer already deals with that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The remote host that you are trying to relay the messages through (74.84.86.134) reverses to spamfilter.coralville.platinum-corp.com.  I assume that this is the MX for the domain that you are trying to send to, (otherwise you probably wouldn't have gotten as far as you did with the SMTP session).  Notwithstanding, it seems that this remote host is accepting messages from your PHP application, but then deciding after receipt of the message that you are not a legitimate mailer, and hence the 'mail not sent' message.

To check mail sent from your application has a glaring problem that would cause other mail servers to think it's spam, try sending a message from your application to check-auth@verifier.port25.com. This service will do a bunch of checks, and you'll get a report back with ton of information, such whether or not your server's DNS forwards and reverses correctly, whether your server's IP is on any black lists, if you have a problem with your SPF records, etc.

Or, a simpler solution might be to just relay these outgoing messages through a well-known SMTP relay, such as smtp.gmail.com, SendGrid, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is true. If it didn't like the sender it should be rejecting earlier (mail servers don't tend to waste their own resources deliberately, even if they're honeytraps), and if it was rejecting for policy reasons it should return a 450 or 550 code. As it stands, it looks like the mail server is set to blackhole the message, for reasons unknown.

Comment: No, it's not uncommon for mail servers to accept an entire message with a 250 OK, then silently discard the message afterwords thinking that it's spam.  In fact, many spam filters apply Bayesian analysis on the body of the message, and this requires receipt of the entire message.

Comment: Sure, but it's unusual for a spam filter to accept and discard rather than reject on this basis since it doesn't discourage future spam. Spam filtering is very expensive, so you want to use it little as possible. This is why things like postscreen exist. Anyway, we need to see the OP's mail server logs and config to diagnose if this is what's happening, or if it's just broken.